# Unsupported Form of Compression

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm in the process of writing a custom CMS solution for a client of mine which generates JavaScript files based on the active site

```
public ActionResult Javascript(string filename)
{
    var fileLocation = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/Views/SiteFiles/{0}/js/{1}", Profile.SiteSlug, filename));
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(fileLocation))
        fileLocation = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/js/{0}", filename));

    return JavaScript(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileLocation));
}
```

Basically, it checks the current sites folder to see if the Javascript file exists there, if it doesn't, it tries to load it from the root js folder, while all the urls look like the files are located in the same folder

The call to the file usually works the first time, and sometimes multiple times, but randomly without changing anything, I begin to get a message from Firefox 
[image]
Chrome shows this message
[image]
When I try to decode the Response from Fiddler, I get this message
[image]

I'm really confused as to what is going on, and what I need to do to fix it

Comment: seems like some problem with the encoding.. are you using Http response compression in IIS or using some HttpModule..

Comment: not using any HttpModule, straight IIS

Comment: well what is the magic number?

Comment: It sounds like your server is sending down a Content-Encoding HTTP Response header, but isn't actually encoding the content. You need to make sure your server doesn't send such a header unless the server is properly compressing the content.

Comment: thanks for the comment EricLaw, I ended up disabling static and dynamic content compression on the Website is IIS and it started working, not sure why it would have been compressing it sometimes and not others, still going to dig deeper into the issue when I get time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up disabling static and dynamic content compression on the Website is IIS and it started working, not sure why it would have been compressing it sometimes and not others, still going to dig deeper into the issue when I get time

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why you are getting an encoding/decoding error, but I worked on a team where we solved a similar problem in a different way.

```
public ActionResult Index( string file, bool? compress )
{
    List< string > requestedFiles;
    if ( file == "documentation" )
    {
        var path = Server.MapPath( "~/Views/Javascript" );
        requestedFiles = Directory.GetFiles( path, "*.js" ).Select( x => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension( x ) ).ToList();
        return View( file, requestedFiles );
    }

    requestedFiles = file.Split( ',' ).Select( x => x.Trim() ).ToList();

    var javascript = new StringBuilder();
    foreach ( var filePath in requestedFiles )
    {
        using ( var fs = new FileStream( Path.Combine( Server.MapPath( "~/Views/Javascript" ), filePath + ".js" ), FileMode.Open ) )
        {
            var bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            fs.Read( bytes, 0, bytes.Length );
            javascript.AppendLine( Encoding.UTF8.GetString( bytes ).Replace( "~/", FullyQulifiedPathToRoot() ) );
        }
    }

    var compressed = javascript.ToString();

    if ( !compress.HasValue || compress == true )
    {
        compressed = JavaScriptCompressor.Compress( javascript.ToString(), true, true, true, false, int.MaxValue, Encoding.UTF8, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, false );
    }

    return JavaScript( compressed );
}

private string FullyQulifiedPathToRoot()
{
    return System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute( "~/" );
}
```

This does require the use of the [Yahoo.Yui.Compressor dll](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)

Comment: hmm... no different. I might try wiring up the YUI compressor and see if that doesn't fix my compression issue... this is frustrating